# how to split string in JSP

Tags: jsp

I have a String in JSP which I need to split by special char `,`. But I'm unable to split it: when trying the code below I'm getting the following error:

```
    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:556)
                                 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:477)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)


    root cause 

    java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jsp.test1jsp_jsp._jspService(test1jsp_jsp.java:115)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)

    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

My Code:

```
<%@page import="sun.security.util.Length"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
  pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
  pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"                                                                               
  http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%
    String arr1 = request.getParameter("arr");
    String[] a = arr1.split(",");
    for(int x=0; x<a.length; x++)
        out.println(a[x]+"<br>");
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, your question is not very clear for now. Please specify and edit your post: is `arr1` the String your are talking about in your question? Is it to split with the `,` separator is what you want? Does `arr1.split(",");` work for you and if not, why? Best regards.

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /try.jsp at line 29 26: String arr1=request.getParameter("arr"); 27: //int count=arr.length; 28: //out.println(arr1); 29: String[] a = arr1.split(","); 30: for(int i=0;i<arr1.length();i++) 31: out.println(a[i]+"<br>"); 32: %>

Comment: Can you try 1st , print the arr1 and verify if the string is NOT null ?

Comment: yaaa its not null I even printed arr1

Comment: I got it thanks for all ur help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just split it in Java? eg

```
String arr1=request.getParameter("arr");
String[] a = arr1.split("yourchar");
```

Comment: What error are you getting? You still have to use a for loop to access each split element in the array. Are you doing this?

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /try.jsp at line 29

26: String arr1=request.getParameter("arr");
27: //int count=arr.length;
28: //out.println(arr1); 
29: String[] a = arr1.split(",");
30: for(int i=0;i<arr1.length();i++)
31:  out.println(a[i]+"<br>");
32: %>

Comment: I think arr1.split(" , ") is not working. Is their any reason for split not working

Comment: Are there actually any commas in your arr1? That could be it

Comment: yes arr1 contains 0,1,2 this should be splited into 0 1 2

Comment: Even i'm getting same error  at this line tooo    for(int i=0;i<arr1.length;i++) at arr1.length

Comment: I want this please help me anyone

Comment: Edit the code to show what you have tried and the error you are getting.

Answer (score 4):

You need to recognize the fact that there are scripting variables and there are scoped variables. In order to make arr1 a scoped variable you need to add something like

```
pageContext.setAttribute("arr1",arr1);
```

to your scriptlet.(I am referring to your initial code)
Actually, you don't need to use a scriptlet. Here is demonstration code.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"                                                                               
  http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing</title>
</head>
<body >
<c:forEach var="splt" items="${fn:split(param.arr1,',')}">
    ${splt} 
</c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: with this i'm not getting anyoutput

Comment: The request for this page must include the parameter. For example,  testPage.jsp?arr1=0,1,2

Comment: Your original code used JSTL. That is why I used it my demonstration code. Did you send the parameter to your second code ? If you didn't, then that would explain the NullPointerException.